# Compose - `fillMaxSize` not working after using `Modifier.verticalScroll`

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating a simple app in Compose with the following layout:

```
    val viewModel: HomeScreenViewModel = viewModel()
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState).fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text(
            "Editor picks".uppercase(),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
        )

        ElevatedCard(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable {

            }.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Column {
                AsyncImage(
                    viewModel.topVideo?.thumbnailSrc,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

The output looks like so:

[image]

The image is not taking up all of the space which I need, it only works if I remove the `Modifier.verticalScroll`, so that the topmost element is just a simple column. When I do that, the output is what I expected:

[image]

I am extremely confused as to why this is happening, as I did not believe that making the root element scrollable would have any effect on the output.

I tried to look for a couple of hours online for solutions and I didn't find anything or any info as to why applying this modifier is ruining the layout.

This other person asked a similar question but the answer didn't work.

Comment: @Abhimanyu What are you on about? I did provide a reproducible example, it depends how large your image is -- if you have a large image it scales well, that's why it worked for you. Try with a smaller image and see how it doesn't scale itself like it should be doing.

Comment: @Abhimanyu try with this image: https://sp.rmbl.ws/s8/1/q/y/n/6/qyn6f.OvCc-small-Rates-Up-Rents-Up-Worse-for.jpg

Comment: Have you ever try to set `fillMaxSize` first then `verticalScroll` on Modifier?

Comment: @axelbrians I tried it and it didn't fix it, the only way to 'fix' it is by setting a fixed height, which I do not want but am forced to use.

Comment: You have a `fillMaxSize()` modifier in your ElevatedCard. A scrolling column has technically infinite height (size). How much space do you want your ElevatedCard to really take?

Comment: @ArpitShukla It should wrap to the content size of the image, and the image should take the maximum width available and the height should be scaled to the correct ratio. It works without the scrolling but once I add in scrolling it breaks it, you can try with my example and use the image link I sent you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your image to fill the entire screen width maintaining the correct aspect ratio, you can set `contentScale` to `ContentScale.FillWidth` for the Image composable.

```kotlin
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)
) {
    Text(
        "Editor picks".uppercase(),
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
    )
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier.clickable {}
    ) {
        Column {
            AsyncImage(
                model = viewModel.topVideo?.thumbnailSrc,
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
    }
}
```